# Extract text prefix and url list to consequtive numbered output line

Tags: curl, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract the "product_sku" from a text file (raw.txt) which has a list of urls. I then need to add the extracted text as a suffix to the end of each url numbered (0-36) to the output file (clean.txt)

Each group of urls has a different "product_sku" so each set of lines needs the "product_sku" which corresponds to the url group.

I am able to extract the urls using the following:

```
cat raw.txt | grep -E -o "WEBSITE/product_images/870-.*" > clean.txt
```

I am struggling to add the "product_sku" to the list.

The code is shown below.

...
... indicates additional urls which have been removed for clarity.

```
var StockNumber = 'U52684'
var product_id = '972930'
var product_sku = 'NN26ZZA'
        var threesixty_start_frame = 4
    var threesixty_images = WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/XafJtPxTqNQuPNQpjF5h.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/9YZH6VMT2zH6AntfaAIG.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/SrE9oVwVmJjS58SwZB9q.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/1enLX6dc9bbG7k9SEAfL.JPG
```

...
...

```
var StockNumber = 'U75102'
var product_id = '768442'
var product_sku = 'LT65YMP'
        var threesixty_start_frame = 4
    var threesixty_images = WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/fg7G7CX2Z0oK8mCVlJN3.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/PGGJ5RaWoYx7VStbsBjL.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/SEEbiNEWA5MXsIUwuaZH.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/TrEPAFaEhxhMxQNDD8qh.JPG
```

...
...

```
var StockNumber = 'U79649'
var product_id = '957033'
var product_sku = 'LS16ZBC'
        var threesixty_start_frame = 4
    var threesixty_images = WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/K5iXEYmG2a4QncRBOrvL.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/fbaj3T5dKtmH0HTX11q5.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/WvBUOrjCMWQGe4gwNhrF.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/ixtB4SbtrFZTIVotvxSd.JPG
```

...
...

Ideal output would look like:

```
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/XafJtPxTqNQuPNQpjF5h.JPG NN26ZZA_01.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/9YZH6VMT2zH6AntfaAIG.JPG NN26ZZA_02.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/SrE9oVwVmJjS58SwZB9q.JPG NN26ZZA_03.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/1enLX6dc9bbG7k9SEAfL.JPG NN26ZZA_04.JPG
...
...
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/fg7G7CX2Z0oK8mCVlJN3.JPG LT65YMP_01.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/PGGJ5RaWoYx7VStbsBjL.JPG LT65YMP_02.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/SEEbiNEWA5MXsIUwuaZH.JPG LT65YMP_03.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/TrEPAFaEhxhMxQNDD8qh.JPG LT65YMP_04.JPG
...
...
```

etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 == "product_sku" {
    sku = $4
    gsub(/\047/,"",sku)
    cnt = 0
}
s = index($0,"WEBSITE/product_images/870-") {
    printf "%s %s_%02d.JPG\n", substr($0,s), sku, ++cnt
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/XafJtPxTqNQuPNQpjF5h.JPG NN26ZZA_01.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/9YZH6VMT2zH6AntfaAIG.JPG NN26ZZA_02.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/SrE9oVwVmJjS58SwZB9q.JPG NN26ZZA_03.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/1enLX6dc9bbG7k9SEAfL.JPG NN26ZZA_04.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/fg7G7CX2Z0oK8mCVlJN3.JPG LT65YMP_01.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/PGGJ5RaWoYx7VStbsBjL.JPG LT65YMP_02.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/SEEbiNEWA5MXsIUwuaZH.JPG LT65YMP_03.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/TrEPAFaEhxhMxQNDD8qh.JPG LT65YMP_04.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/K5iXEYmG2a4QncRBOrvL.JPG LS16ZBC_01.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/fbaj3T5dKtmH0HTX11q5.JPG LS16ZBC_02.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/WvBUOrjCMWQGe4gwNhrF.JPG LS16ZBC_03.JPG
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/ixtB4SbtrFZTIVotvxSd.JPG LS16ZBC_04.JPG
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` to capture the product_sku seen in the previous line and reuse it as per the requirement. For example, here  product_sku is used to on all the lines having `WEBSITE`. Note that counter of `c` is also reset every time when product_sku is seen. So that the numbering will restart for each product_sku.

```
awk  '/product_sku/{p_sku=$NF; c=1;next} /WEBSITE/{url=gensub(/.*(WEBSITE.*)/,"\\1","g");print url,p_sku "_"c".jpeg";c++}' input
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/XafJtPxTqNQuPNQpjF5h.JPG NN26ZZA_1.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/9YZH6VMT2zH6AntfaAIG.JPG NN26ZZA_2.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/SrE9oVwVmJjS58SwZB9q.JPG NN26ZZA_3.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-972930/1enLX6dc9bbG7k9SEAfL.JPG NN26ZZA_4.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/fg7G7CX2Z0oK8mCVlJN3.JPG LT65YMP_1.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/PGGJ5RaWoYx7VStbsBjL.JPG LT65YMP_2.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/SEEbiNEWA5MXsIUwuaZH.JPG LT65YMP_3.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-768442/TrEPAFaEhxhMxQNDD8qh.JPG LT65YMP_4.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/K5iXEYmG2a4QncRBOrvL.JPG LS16ZBC_1.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/fbaj3T5dKtmH0HTX11q5.JPG LS16ZBC_2.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/WvBUOrjCMWQGe4gwNhrF.JPG LS16ZBC_3.jpeg
WEBSITE/product_images/870-957033/ixtB4SbtrFZTIVotvxSd.JPG LS16ZBC_4.jpeg
```

Note: This solution requires, `gawk` to run.

Comment: @PS. you may need to add `gsub("\047", "", $NF);` prior to `p_sku=$NF;` to remove single quotes as the OP points out.

Comment: @Demartini change the print statement in above command to `printf "%s %s%s%02d%s\n", url, p_sku, "_", c, ".jpeg"; `